# How to get cell value on React-Bootstrap-Table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I develop in React.js, and I'm using React-Bootstrap-Table. I need to get cell value on a sepcific column.

Is it possible to get cell value on a column ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's okay ! 
This is the solution :

```
editFormatter(cell, row)  {row.nom_de_la_colonne}
```